# How do I recursively go through directories and name a file after the directory?

Tags: bash

What I am attempting to do is combine all of the files within a subdirectory into a new file, and give the new combined file the same name as the subdirectory, and I have no idea how to do this in Bash. Here's how I approached it: I have a number of directories, each with a unique file name (with spaces!). Within each of these directories, there are a number of numerically named files, like thus:

```
Home/Unique name/1.pdf  
Home/Unique name/2.pdf  
Home/Unique name/3.pdf  
Home/Unique name/4.pdf  
....  
Home/Other Unique name/1.pdf  
Home/Other Unique name/2.pdf  
Home/Other Unique name/3.pdf  
Home/Other Unique name/4.pdf
```

What I would like to do is write a bash script (from the `Home` directory) to:

1. Go into each unique directory, and perform a command on each of the files within that directory (in my case, copy them all to a different directory).
2. I have then written a different script `script.sh` that will perform another command (in this case, combine all the PDFs into a single file, `temp.pdf`). I would then like to rename that `temp.pdf` file after the directory `Unique name.pdf` (with spaces).
3. I will have to follow this process for a number of subdirectories.

I have attempted a solution with a number of for loops, while loops and using the find command, but I am not comfortable enough with bash to debug comfortably or use these variables with any degree of confidence. I am also certain that there is a more efficient way to do what I am doing, but I have bootstrapped the script together over a period of time.

Comment: Should be a relatively simple C or Java program.

Comment: Unless you're doing this for plain-text encoded files, the resulting files will **not** be considered valid.  For example, if you just concatenate the binary data in a few PDFs, the resulting file is **not** a PDF-compliant file (if you're lucky, it **might** show you the first PDF only).  You need a specific tool for the format of files you want to join.  To join several files, however, you can just use `cat` to display them all in the proper order, and pipe the results of `cat` into a new file.

Comment: @DanielRHicks using C for something this simple would be *hilariously* overkill

Answer (score 1):

The POSIX way is to use `print . -type d ... | while read f; do`, but unless you're obsessed with 100% portability, I wouldn't bother with that. If you have bash 4+ and `pdfunite` (installed by default on my Ubuntu 13.04), you can do this in two lines:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in ./**/; do pdfunite "$f"/*.pdf "$f"/"$(basename "$f").pdf"; done
```

Note that `shopt -s globstar` needs to be on a separate line to the rest of it. With globstar enabled, `**` expands to all files and directories in the current directory, recursively. Since files cannot contain `/` in their names, `**/` will expand to only the directories. I use `./**/` in the unlikely event that your directories begin with a hyphen (`-`), as this can cause problems, since many programs treat anything beginning with a `-` as an option.

As written, this will not copy the PDFs to another directory, but that's pretty trivial to add in:

```
for f in ./**/; do cp "$f"/*.pdf /target/dir/; pdfunite "$f"/*.pdf "$f"/"$(basename "$f").pdf"; done
```

If you want to use your own custom pdf-combining script, then simply change the line to suit - but remember that the essence of shell scripting is putting together pre-existing commands.

Here's a somewhat more portable version:

```
print . -type d -print0 | while read -d $'\0' f; do
  pdfunite "$f"/*.pdf "$f"/"$(basename "$f").pdf"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create `for` loop with `find /home/ -type f -name "*.pdf"` as a variable
2. Copy files to where you need them to, take $VARIABLE and process it through sed/awk to remove "/".

Post your script and we can help you to improve it.

You can always run scripts with `bash -x` to debug them or you can set `!#/bin/bash -x` to always execute in debug (verbose) mode.